# Springcloud multiple data source @RefreshScope error

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I am performing multiple data sources hot update configuration data error can not be executed。

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = DruidCrmDBConfig.PACKAGE,sqlSessionFactoryRef = DruidCrmDBConfig.NAME+"SessionFactory")
public class DruidCrmDBConfig {
    ...
@RefreshScope
@Bean(name=NAME+"DataSource")    //声明其为Bean实例
//    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring."+NAME)
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DruidDataSource datasource = new DruidDataSource();
    datasource.setUrl(this.dbUrl);
        ...
}
```

}

```
   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

    Action:

    If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod" are currently active).
```

Comment: Can you say why you think this is an issue with refresh scope?

Comment: Removing a source @RefreshScope is operational. Just can't hot update

Comment: Do you have the datasource related properties like `datasource url` , `driver-class-name` in `application-prod.properties`?

Comment: use cloud-config to update，remove @RefreshScope is nomal

Comment: Items such as your database configuration that is used by Spring Data won’t be reloaded by the @RefreshScope annotation.